# Replacing images from ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview

I am new to android and trying to develop a game. I am trying to replace images in my `ImageView` on recursive function call after some delay. The problem I am facing is that if once an image is set to the `ImageView` it is not changing though the function is being called every time.

I have used both `setImageResource()` and `setImageDrawable()` but still could not achieve desired result.
Can someone help me?

The function I am using to do this is:

`type` and `laneNumber` are passed from the calling function `play()`

```
int images[] = {R.drawable.blue, R.drawable.bluesq, R.drawable.red, R.drawable.redsq};
void play()
{
   type = random.nextInt(2);
   laneNumber = random.nextInt(4);
   createBlock(type,laneNumber);
   if(--count>0)
   {
     play();
   }
}

void createBlock(int type, int laneNumber) {
   switch (laneNumber) 
   {            
     case 0:
       selector = 0;
       objectLane1.setImageResource(images[type+selector]);
       animateDown(objectLane1);
       break;
     case 1:
       selector = 0;
       objectLane1.setImageResource(images[type+selector]);
       animateDown(objectLane1);
       break;
     case 2:
       selector =2;
       objectLane1.setImageResource(images[type+selector]);
       animateDown(objectLane1);
       break;
     case 3:
       selector = 2;
       objectLane1.setImageResource(images[type+selector]);
       animateDown(objectLane1);
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: where you calling play();

Comment: I think your recursive calls just fall through the end. You have no waiting period for the change to be visible. Try adding some fixed sleep, or `AnimationListener` to wait for the animation to end.

Comment: in `onCreate()` of my activity

Comment: how can i add a fixed sleep ?

Comment: `AnimationListener` did the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no waiting period between recursive calls, there is no way to see ImageView change, even if it does occur.

**Solution:**

Wait for the animation to finish by using `AnimationListener`. This way next recursive will not execute before animation finishes.

Comment: @Jay.jk Great, glad it worked. You can help the community by accepting the answer that proved useful and/or upvote.

Comment: I had marked it useful but i am new to stackOverflow so my upvotes are not shown :)